# Google charts timeline with relative "timestamps"

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, timestamp, google-visualization

I'm trying to visualise speedrun times in a linechart, per date. I have the following data:

| ID | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-20 00:00:00 | 1:59:11.19 |
| 2 | 2021-10-21 00:00:00 | 1:55:33.43 |
| 3 | 2021-10-22 00:00:00 | 1:54:52.82 |
| 4 | 2021-10-23 00:00:00 | 1:53:44.15 |

The data will be converted to an array, as such;

```js
var runs = [
    [1, "2021-10-20 00:00:00", "1:59:11.19"],
    [2, "2021-10-21 00:00:00", "1:55:33.43"],
    [3, "2021-10-22 00:00:00", "1:54:52.82"],
    [4, "2021-10-23 00:00:00", "1:53:44.15"]
];
```

I tried following the example from the [dev docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart), and the example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) without any luck. As they only show examples that support numbers or absolute datetimes / created times.

Is there a way to make a linechart work with relative times (including ms), showing all times chronologically per date?

Comment: Post code here, the JSFiddle link is already broken. "*I have the following data*" do you mean as HTML or text with delimiters? Are you trying to process text or a DOM? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

if you are wanting to display the date on the x-axis and the time on the y-axis,
you can use google's [timeofday](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday) data type for the y-axis

> The DataTable timeofday column data type takes an array of either 3 or 4 numbers, representing hours, minutes, seconds, and optionally milliseconds, respectively.
> For example, the time 8:30am would be: [8, 30, 0, 0]

following is routine used to build data table

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');

for (var i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
  // convert date
  var rowDate = new Date(runs[i][1]);
  
  // convert time to timeofday data type [h, m, sec, ms]
  var rowTime = runs[i][2].split(':');
  var ms = rowTime[rowTime.length - 1].split('.');
  rowTime = rowTime.map(function (timeValue, index) {
    if (index === (rowTime.length - 1)) {
      return parseInt(ms[0]);
    } else {
      return parseInt(timeValue);
    }
  });
  rowTime.push(parseInt(ms[1]));
  
  // add data row
  data.addRow([rowDate, rowTime]);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var runs = [
    [1, "2021-10-20 00:00:00", "1:59:11.19"],
    [2, "2021-10-21 00:00:00", "1:55:33.43"],
    [3, "2021-10-22 00:00:00", "1:54:52.82"],
    [4, "2021-10-23 00:00:00", "1:53:44.15"]
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');

  for (var i = 0; i < runs.length; i++) {
    // convert date
    var rowDate = new Date(runs[i][1]);
    
    // convert time to timeofday data type [h, m, sec, ms]
    var rowTime = runs[i][2].split(':');
    var ms = rowTime[rowTime.length - 1].split('.');
    rowTime = rowTime.map(function (timeValue, index) {
      if (index === (rowTime.length - 1)) {
        return parseInt(ms[0]);
      } else {
        return parseInt(timeValue);
      }
    });
    rowTime.push(parseInt(ms[1]));
    
    // add data row
    data.addRow([rowDate, rowTime]);
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 40,
      left: 64,
      right: 40,
      bottom: 40
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```